# iterating list values to update multiple fields

Tags: apex, trigger, community, controller

Though the below code is working fine, since its not the right practice to hardcode index numbers so is there any alternate approach for the below code. - thanks

```
 List<Contact> cntList = [Select id,LastName,Amount__c from Contact where AccountId = 'xyzadsd34' and Amount__c != Null order by Amount__c  DESC];
        List<Opportunity> oppList  = new List<Opportunity>();

         Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
            opp.Name = 'Test-';
            opp.CloseDate = System.today();
            opp.StageName = 'Prospecting';   
            opp.Amount1__c = cntList[0].Amount__c;
            opp.Amount2__c = cntList[1].Amount__c;
            opp.Amount3__c = cntList[2].Amount__c;
            opp.Amount4__c = cntList[3].Amount__c;
             oppList.add(opp);


        insert oppList;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use some dynamic Apex:

```
Contact[] records = [SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...];
SObjectField[] fields = new SObjectField[] {
  Opportunity.Amount1__c, Opportunity.Amount2__c, Opportunity.Amount3__c, Opportunity.Amount4__c
};
Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
// other fields here //
for(Integer i = 0, s = Math.min(records.size(), fields.size()); i < s; i++) {
  opp.put(fields[i], records[i].Amount__c);
}
oppList.add(opp);
```

Comment: @sfdxfox Thank you for your valuable time and response it worked out n i learnt something new today.